# Django - Embed python inside HTML to trigger two form actions

Tags: python, html, django

All I want to do is to have a condition in order when the user clicks **FOR SALE** button to be redirected to **url 'salesearch'** or when clicks **TO RENT** to be redirected to **url 'rentsearch'**.

Here's the code:

```html
 <div class="search">
  <form action="{% url 'salesearch' %}">
   <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
     <label class="sr-only">
      Keywords
     </label>
     <input class="form-control" name="keywords" placeholder="Keyword (Pool, Garage, etc)" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
     <label class="sr-only">
      City
     </label>
     <input class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" name="For Sale" type="submit">
       For Sale
      </button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" name="To Rent" type="submit">
       To Rent
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

With the above example I am redirected always at url 'salesearch path. Is there any way to have a conditional to determine the url's path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is!

You can set [`formaction` on `button` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

```
<button name="For Sale" type="submit" formaction="{% url 'salesearch' %}">
For Sale
</button>
<button name="To Rent" type="submit" formaction="{% url 'rentsearch' %}">
To Rent
</button>
```